# Cron expression except between 8 am to 10 am

Tags: cron

I want to create a cron expression to allow except between 8 am to 10 am everyday.

```
* 0-8,10-23
```

is this right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please see the following help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you mean to write **except**?

Comment: Questions about `cron` would be more appropriate in Superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com. SO is for computer programming questions.

Comment: @Bramar yes except

Comment: except != expect, they are different words with different meanings. I would suggest to check both words with a dictionary of your native language. I fixed your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's right.

Note it should have five fields (minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week) before the command line, or before the username and command line :

system-wide crontab:

```
* 0-8,10-23 * * * root command args
```

or user crontab:

```
* 0-8,10-23 * * * command args
```